# codeforces shows WA but output is correct on terminal

Tags: c++

When I submitted my solution for codeforces 551C , the judge gives me a Wrong Answer on 49th test case. But when I run the same code on my terminal (using g++4.9.2) the answer comes out to be correct.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
#define endl '\n'
using namespace std;

template <class T>
inline void dbg(string s,T &a)
{
      cout << s+" is => " << a << endl;
}

int n,m;
int a[100005];
bool check(long long int time)
{
      long long int consumed,temp=0,diff;
      for(int i=1;n!=0 && i<=m;i++)
      {
            consumed=n;
            while(n>0 && consumed<time)
            {
                  if(!temp)
                        temp=a[n];
                  diff=temp<(time-consumed)?temp:time-consumed;
                  temp-=diff;
                  consumed+=diff;
                  if(!temp)
                        n--;
            }
      }
      if(n==0)
            return true;
      else
            return false;
}

int main()
{
      cin >> n >> m;
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            cin >> a[i];

      while(a[n]==0) n--;
      long long int last_nonempty=n,l=n+1,r=LONG_MAX,mid;

      while(l<r)
      {
            mid=l+(r-l)/2;
            n=last_nonempty;
            if(check(mid))
                  r=mid;
            else
                  l=mid+1;
      }
      cout << l << endl;

      return 0;
}
```

The link to my submission is : http://codeforces.com/contest/551/submission/11582619

Please help.

Comment: By the way, adding spaces around operators would make your code more readable and not affect execution time.  If the online judge gives you error for it, choose a different method to learn.

Comment: I highly recommend using a debugger (`gdb`) or an IDE with a debugger and using the input values from the test case that produces the wrong answer.  The wrong answer case looks like you have overflow in your code.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your inicializtion.And in your own IDE,the deaults is right,but it is wrong on OJ.